# Dual Boot USB Drive

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, multi-boot

I can install Windows 7 from USB. I can also install a Linux distro from USB. Is there a way of doing both?

Like, plugging in the USB drive and choosing Windows and installing Windows, or choosing -let's say- Ubuntu and installing Ubuntu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. Essentially, you need to copy as many installation CDs (ISOs) as you want on to the pendrive and then use a bootloader (such as GRUB) to boot from the one you want.

Here are a few of the *many* programs that can help you set it up:

- [Live USB creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)
- [Live USB multiboot](http://liveusb.info/dotclear/)
- [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)
- [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)

A great source of information for this kind of thing is the [pendrive linux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com) website.