# grub-install gives an error message I don't understand

Tags: linux, grub, centos-6

I'm new to Linux, am using CentOS 6.3, and am attempting to install CentOS 5.8 ISO to a pen drive following instructions from [here](http://ihazem.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/installing-centos-from-usb).

My pen drive is `/dev/sda` and partition 1 is `vfat`. It's mounted on `/mnt/usb`. Here's what happens when I try to use `grub-install`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# grub-install –root-directory=/mnt/usb /dev/sda

More than one install_devices?
Usage: grub-install [OPTION] install_device
Install GRUB on your drive.

-h, --help
       print this message and exit

-v, --version
       print the version information and exit

--root-directory=DIR
       install GRUB images under the directory DIR instead of the root directory

--grub-shell=FILE
       use FILE as the grub shell

--no-floppy
       do not probe any floppy drive

--force-lba
       force GRUB to use LBA mode even for a buggy BIOS

--recheck
       probe a device map even if it already exists
       This flag is unreliable and its use is strongly discouraged.

 INSTALL_DEVICE can be a GRUB device name or a system device filename.

 grub-install copies GRUB images into the DIR/boot directory specfied by --root-directory, and uses the grub shell to install grub into the boot sector.
```

I don't understand the error message in this context, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are copying the commands directly from the webpage and this results in your pasting an [em dash](http://codepoints.net/U+2014) (—) instead of two consecutive [minus signs](http://codepoints.net/U+002D) (--) which is what you need to use. All long (--foo-bar) options in *nix are given with two consecutive minus signs. So, try this:

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/usb /dev/sda
```

Note the difference between `–boot-directory` and `--boot-directory`.

Comment: Got the same error message.  The grub I have is version 0.97.  How do I install grub2 if this version is not grub2?

Comment: I chose Centos because I need to install an Advanced Silicon frame grabber and their driver, which I need to install, needs to be installed under SUSE or Redhat and kernel 2.6.  The instructions from the vendor broke under Centos 6.3 and I was advised by someone who maintains several Centos machines to fall back to Centos 5.8.  I had used Ubuntu bucause of its ease of installation.

Comment: Personally, @Nate,  I would recommend SUSE (or, even better, openSUSE). It will make your life easier. Anyway, have a look at my updated answer, I figured out what was going on.

Comment: There should have been a double dash for the option.  It may have run correctly and gave me this: This is the contents of the device map /mnt/usb/boot/grub/device.map.
Check if this is correct or not. If any of the lines is incorrect,
fix it and re-run the script `grub-install'.

(fd0) /dev/fd0
(hd0) /dev/sda  (pen-drive)
(hd1) /dev/sdb  (internal SDD boot} 
(hd2) /dev/sdc

Comment: Thanks, our comments are crossing in cyberspace.  I need the source code to install the driver and I understood that for SUSE the code must be purchased on a CD and the instructions are in German.  If that's not true I'll try it!  I'm distro agnostic (or ignorent).

Comment: @Nate, yes, I realized the dash problem and updated my answer. Please post a new question if you have problems further down the line. Also, do have a look at the [link](http://superuser.com/a/480454/151431) I posted, you are trying to do this in the most difficult of the possible ways.

Comment: Look at [openSUSE](http://www.opensuse.org/en/) first. Oh, and something that works for Redhat will probably work for any rpm-based distro (e.g. SUSE, openSUSE, Fedora, CentOS and many others.). See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions#RPM-based) for a list.

Comment: The links you give appear to be for PCs (aka Windows) or for dual boot.  I need to make a clean install. I will continue but look into openSUSE,too.

Comment: @Nate, only the first one is for windows. The rest work on Linux.

Comment: is --boot-directory and --root-directory same?