# grub-install gives error message I don't understand

Tags: linux, centos, grub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [grub-install gives an error message I don’t understand](https://superuser.com/questions/544113/grub-install-gives-an-error-message-i-dont-understand)

I'm new to Linux, am using CentOS 6.3, and am attempting to install CentOS 5.8 ISO to a pen-drive following instructions from here: http://ihazem.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/installing-centos-from-usb/

My pen-drive is /dev/sda and partion 1 is vfat.  It's mounted on /mnt/usb.  Here's what happens when I try to use grub-install:

```
[root@localhost ~]# grub-install –root-directory=/mnt/usb /dev/sda
```

This is the error message I get which I don't understand in this context:

"More than one install_devices?
Usage: grub-install [OPTION] install_device
Install GRUB on your drive.

-h, --help              print this message and exit
  -v, --version           print the version information and exit
  --root-directory=DIR    install GRUB images under the directory DIR
                          instead of the root directory
  --grub-shell=FILE       use FILE as the grub shell
  --no-floppy             do not probe any floppy drive
  --force-lba             force GRUB to use LBA mode even for a buggy
                          BIOS
  --recheck               probe a device map even if it already exists
                          This flag is unreliable and its use is
                          strongly discouraged.

INSTALL_DEVICE can be a GRUB device name or a system device filename.

grub-install copies GRUB images into the DIR/boot directory specfied by
--root-directory, and uses the grub shell to install grub into the boot
sector."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one `-` in front of your `root-directory` option, so it isn't being interpreted as a long option. What you want is `--root-directory=/mnt/usb` (instead of `-root...` as you have).

Comment: Thanks, I did notice this some time after posting.  I c&p and edited the command and thought that the source had two hyphens that displayed as one and then didn't notice the difference in the copied text.  Mea culpa.